# what is the meaning of check_ret in unix

Tags: unix

can you please explain what is check_ret....Explain with example....

check_ret "Extract of rec count from filename $orig_file" quiet

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certainly a shell function that check the shell return code (like `$?`) from the previous statement and outputs a message if it's not zero.

I'd guess that the `quiet` option would be for only outputting an error message on failure rather than an error/success message no matter what.

But that's mostly supposition based on experience. Whatever it is, it's not standard UNIX so you should be looking at your functions with something like `typeset -f` or aliases with `alias` (depending on your shell).

A cursory search of the web shows up [this possibility](https://github.com/jckarter/factor/blob/master/build-support/factor.sh):

```
check_ret() {
    RET=$?
    if [[ $RET -ne 0 ]] ; then
       $ECHO $1 failed
       exit_script 2
    fi
}
```

which is basically what I described although, obviously, that has no `quiet` option checking in it so it's only an approximation.